# JSON with JRuby - Not parsing the result in UTF-8

Tags: ruby, json, jruby

I am using [JSON implementation for Ruby](http://flori.github.com/json/) in my rails project to parse the JSON string sent by ajax, but I found that although the json string is in UTF-8, the result coming out is in `ASCII-8BIT` by default, see below

```
jruby-1.6.7 :068 > json_text = '["に到着を待っている"]'
 => "[\"に到着を待っている\"]"
jruby-1.6.7 :069 > json_text.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
jruby-1.6.7 :070 > json_parsed = JSON.parse(json_text)
 => ["\u00E3\u0081\u00AB\u00E5\u0088\u00B0\u00E7\u009D\u0080\u00E3\u0082\u0092\u00E5\u00BE\u0085\u00E3\u0081\u00A3\u00E3\u0081\u00A6\u00E3\u0081\u0084\u00E3\u0082\u008B"]
jruby-1.6.7 :071 > json_parsed.first.encoding
 => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

I don't want it being escaped, I would like to have a UTF-8 result. Is there a way to set that? I check the documentation of the JSON project, finding not encoding options for the method `JSON.parse`. Maybe I missed something, how could I do that?

**UPDATE:**
as notified by @fl00r, this example is working fine in MRI, but not in JRUBY

Comment: It might help to set `Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8`, but I'm not sure how that works on JRuby

Comment: Thanks a lot @fl00r for pointing out that, I didn't think of trying in MRI, though I run all my tests on MRI. @Darth seeing `Encoding.default_internal` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, as this actually works when using the pure version:

```
jruby-1.6-head :001 > require 'json/pure'
 => true 
jruby-1.6-head :002 > json_text = '["に到着を待っている"]'
 => "[\"に到着を待っている\"]" 
jruby-1.6-head :003 > json_parsed = JSON.parse(json_text)
 => ["に到着を待っている"] 
jruby-1.6-head :004 > json_parsed.first.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
jruby-1.6-head :005 >
```

**Edit:** Just saw you opened a [ticket](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/126) for this...

**Edit 2:** This actually seems to have already been fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/flori/json/commit/c93d679936aa5658c700b5c84367211e84b16238).  To install latest code from `json`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/flori/json.git
$ cd json
$ rake jruby_gem
$ jruby -S gem install pkg/json-1.6.6-java.gem
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the findings. Yes, just after discovering it's working in MRI not in JRUBY i opened a ticket for it. What's the difference between `json` and `json/pure`?

Comment: `json` normally uses a C implementation (or in the case of JRuby a Java implementation) to parse JSON, but it also provides a pure ruby implementation as a fallback.

Comment: Thanks, let's see how the ticket goes, are you one of the dev from JSON?

Comment: Updated again, this seems to have been fixed already.  I am not a json dev, just a jruby lover!